# How to speed up MySQLl loading from dump file of a very large database around 1T of tables?

Tags: server, mysql, backup, database, sql

i have 1T in around 200 tales in aws rds of innoDB , i want to backup them and restore in ubuntu 16.0.4 server , i tried with `mysql-dump mysqldump --single-transaction --quick --max_allowed_packet 1G` and then restore via `mysql -u <mu_user_name> -p<my_pwd>  <mu_db_name> < /mnt/rds.sql` , the dump took several hours and created file in size of 256G ,the restore  process has not done for 5 days, how can i make this processes faster ? maybe with different option to mysql? or a faster tool for restore very large databases? what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

faster : mysqlimport

```
mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1 [textfile2 ...]
```

More info : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html

You can also temporary tune the mysqld config

```
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
```